# Flexbox columns equal height using Bootstrap 4.4, Wordpress, & Bootstrap Shortcodes Ultimate plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, plugins, flexbox

My *WordPress 5.6* template uses *Bootstrap 4.4*, and also has the *Bootstrap Shortcodes Ultimate* plugin.

I have two columns that I want to sit side by side, and maintain equal height even when changing screen size.

Since it is a **WordPress site**, I have used the **Bootstrap Shortcodes Ultimate plugin** to create the row & col with *shortcodes*, to make it easier for the client to edit the column's content (without messing up the layout structure).  Unfortunately, then means I can't add a class to the divs with row or column.

I thought this wouldn't be a problem as bootstrap 4.4 uses flexbox naturally, and I figured I wouldn't need to add any extra css to control the flexbox settings.

But that doesn't appear to be the case.

Right now, with the current wording in each column, the columns are the same size except when the view-port gets smaller (eg: between 494 & 767 - where eventually the content of one column ends up having more lines than the other).

Here is the jsfiddle example of the two columns: https://jsfiddle.net/SunnyOz/ofgp3n8d/24/.  If you adjust the screen size small enough, you will eventually see that the first column will be longer the then second column as the column width sizes get smaller.

If I do an "inspect element" on the columns, this is the html code I see:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="u-shadow-v3 font-bigger g-bg-yellow g-brd-around g-brd-gray-light-v4 g-line-height-2 g-pa-40 g-mb-30">Click here to review our approach to <a href="http://www.haregroup.com.au/performance_reward_management.asp">finding solutions to performance &amp; reward challenges</a>.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
            <div class="u-shadow-v3 font-bigger g-bg-yellow g-brd-around g-brd-gray-light-v4 g-line-height-2 g-pa-40 g-mb-30">Click here to read about <a href="http://www.haregroup.com.au/generator/assets/when_has_good_performance_been_more_important_31july20sh.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">a current challenge in&nbsp;performance &amp; reward management</a>.
           </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is my style.css code that relates to the columns:

```
body {
font-family: 'Open-Baskerville-0053', 'Times New Roman', Georgia, serif;
font-size: 20px;
color: #333;
}

.font-bigger {
font-size: 1.2em;
}

.u-shadow-v3::after, .u-shadow-v3::before, .u-shadow-v4::before, .u-shadow-v5::after {
box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

.u-shadow-v3::after, .u-shadow-v3::before, .u-shadow-v4::before, .u-shadow-v5::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 80%;
left: 0.35714rem;
bottom: 1.07143rem;
width: 50%;
max-width: 21.42857rem;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
z-index: -1;              
}


.g-pa-40 {
padding: 2.85714rem !important;
}
.g-pa-40 {
padding: 2.85714rem !important;
}
.g-mb-30 {
margin-bottom: 2.14286rem !important;
}
.g-line-height-2 {
line-height: 2 !important;
}
.g-brd-gray-light-v4 {
border-color: #eee !important;
}
.g-brd-around {
border: solid 1px transparent !important;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}
.g-bg-white {
background-color: #fff !important;
}
.g-bg-yellow {
color: #000000;
background-color: #fffdca !important;
border-radius: 12px;
}

.g-bg-yellow a {
color: #008080;

}
.g-bg-yellow a:hover, .g-bg-yellow a:hover, .g-bg-yellow a:focus, .g-bg-yellow a:active {
color: #cc9900;
}

.u-shadow-v3, .u-shadow-v4, .u-shadow-v5 {
position: relative;
}

.u-shadow-v3::after, .u-shadow-v5::after {
left: auto;
right: 0.35714rem;
-webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
transform: rotate(3deg);
}
```

Below are some of the css that is displayed from the 'inspect element' styles section, that is taken from other .css files besides my main style.css - that also relate to the style of the row/col.

css from from _grid.scss:45:

```
.row {
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
}
```

and css from _grid-framework.scss:31

```
.col {
-ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
flex-basis: 0;
-ms-flex-positive: 1;
flex-grow: 1;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

and css from _grid-framework.scss:8

```
.col, .col-1, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-auto {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
}
```

and css from bootstrap.css: 40

```
*, ::after, ::before {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

As you can see, it appears that the flex code is being set (being pulled in by bootstrap natively) - as in: `display: flex;`, `flex-wrap: wrap;` `flex-basis: 0;`, and `flex-grow: 1;`.

So what am I missing?

As I mentioned before, I can't add a class to the `<div class="row">` or `<div class="col">`, as that is controlled by the plugin's short code.

Is there anyway I can get the columns to always stay equal no matter what the screen size is - with my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code link? Hope it will work for you. You need to just set the height to **.u-shadow-v3, .u-shadow-v4, .u-shadow-v5** like..

```
.u-shadow-v3, .u-shadow-v4, .u-shadow-v5 {
    position: relative;
    height: calc(100% - 2.14286rem);
}
```

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/q8orcv2j/5/

Comment: Wow.. thanks so much.  I thought that adding a height parameter would mess with responsiveness, but it doesn't appear to interfere with it.  Everything works like a charm!!  Just out of curiosity, is the calculation required at this location due to the shadow size?

Comment: First of all, We are glad that, our solution helped you... 
This calculation not due to the shadow size. It depends upon the margin-bottom (class "g-mb-30"). 
If you set margin-bottom is 30 than height will be "calc(100% - 32px)".